# Create Password List of specific length words and combine it with a dictionary, in combination with a character set

Tags: string, dictionary, passwords, word-list

Let's say all passwords should be 4 characters long use a dictionary and a-z and 0-9

1car 2car ..

car1 car2 ..

acar bcar ..

cara carb ..

Any known tool that can generate this. It's going to be used for specific length passwords that contain 1 or more words in the rest is generated with all combinatory possibilities using defined character sets.

Comment: Maybe KeyPass2 is the way you could go

Comment: I'm not looking to store a password, but generate millions on the fly, containing words and combination of words and random characters.